# Vehicle speeds when plotting isochrones by time

Tags: routes, here-api

I am trying to find information on the vehicle speeds used when plotting drivetime isochrones, particularly HGV isochrones.

I have a 1-hour drive time from a single point that is different when using other software.  For other software I have learned that the distance travelled is based on the speed limit, any vehicle speed restrictions (HGVs in this instance) and deductions made based on the surface of the carriageway.

Does the HERE API just use speed limits of roads?

Answer (score 0):

HERE calculates the route duration not only based on the speed limit. There are many more factors included, such as the departure time of travel, route geometry, traffic situation and so on. Many parameters can also be tweaked. For example, a route can be calculated with different route optimization modes that will also affect the ETA.